# Slickgrid-Column header filter with Pagination

Tags: slickgrid

I worked on slickgrid with header row filter(each column),pagination option is not available in the example grid.
   Is it possible to add pagination with header row filter.

Regards,
Rajendhiran M

Comment: These are all blocks, just pick the blocks you need and add it within your project... you might need to include CSS or JS file, just check in the pagination example which file is needed

Answer (score 2):

As @ghiscoding mentioned, you just need to fit the pager block in your page.

1. First get pager control plug-in (slick.pager.js)

`<script src="../path/to/SlickGrid/controls/slick.pager.js"></script>`

2. Now add an additional div for pager, just below the div that contains the grid

`<div id="pager" style="width:100%;height:20px;"></div>`

3. Now in JavaScript section, initialize the pager

`grid = new Slick.Grid( "#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);
 var pager = new Slick.Controls.Pager(dataView, grid, $("#pager"));`

Done.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply.I have one more question how to dynamically get data in the slickgrid pagingination.Is it possible in slickgrid.

Comment: First thing first, nothing is impossible! Just like any other library, you can use PHP, Perl, Python, AJAX etc to dynamically populate the SlickGrid data array. Pager plug-in updates automatically when SlickGrid data is updated. Does that answer your question?